# CakePHP: Get model instance by url string

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

I have a CakePHP website and navigaton links are stored in database. What i want is for some navigation entries to call custom function which will return some additional, dynamic data about the link: I want to add a count of articles for link "Vacancies". I could call a function on a model that would return total count. This link is to be rendered on every page.

So i need to get appropriate models instance, but not for the current request, but the request where url points to.

So basically i have url "/en/vacancies". I can get controller name by:

```
 $urlInfo = Router::parse("/en/vacancies");
 $controllerName = $urlInfo['controller'];
```

What would be the reliable way to do that?

Any other solutions for the problem are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the method to gather the navigation link data in a `Model`.

```
App::import('Controller', $controllerName);
$controller = new $controllerName;

$controller->loadModel('YourModel');
$yourModel = $controller->YourModel;

$yourData = $yourModel->your_method();
```

There are a variety of other ways to do this.  But, without knowing more about where you're actually going to be calling this function I can't really provide anymore suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. I`ll try this in a working day. I am enumerating links in AppController, but from there i need to call that custom model function for each link that points somwhere on my site (and therefore has a controller/model)

Comment: Does each link have a different controller/model or is it the same code for each?

Comment: Links can either share or not share model. But anyway thank you, this works and therefore is solved.

Comment: What about `$yourModel =& ClassRegistry::init($this->modelClass);` ?

Comment: @PhilippeRathé Since I answered this question I have since stopped using Cake for my projects.  However, I would stay away from doing references in PHP5 as they are almost always unnecessary.  If memory serves correctly the `loadModel()` method will only load the model if it has not already been instantiated.  I could be wrong on this but at the time this is what the research I did indicated was the best solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this solution works for me when I don't know the name of the default model used by the controller because the code is use by other controllers which all use different models.